# Custom Cell UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to have a custom cell in my UITableview.  I have tried it with the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (UIView *view in views) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (CustomCell*)view;
        }
    }
}
[cell setLabelText:[daten objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;

}
```

But I am  getting an exception on that line:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: paste the exception log.

Comment: Have you created the custom cell in another class ??

Comment: 2012-09-24 12:30:33.514 Speedcheck[1183:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CustomCell 0x1c55ca40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key commentLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x34d532a3 0x3452597f 0x34d52f99 0x39caf9d1 0x37a2f1e1 0x39cab723 0x34cd961b 0x37a28245 0x378d672f 0xd8b27 0x378d654d 0x378bb313 0x378d27cf 0x3788e80b 0x33f05d63 0x33f05901 0x33f06835 0x33f0621b 0x33f06029 0x378948f3 0x34d286cd 0x34d269c1 0x34d26d17 0x34c99ebd 0x34c99d49 0x35a022eb 0x378df301 0xaa133 0x3991eb20)
lib

Comment: put a breakpoint on `cell = (CustomCell *)view`.  does it return a cell?  Is the class of the cell set in the nib file?

Comment: no it doesn´t return a cell, cause i get an exception earlier...Yep the class is set in the my Storyboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost sure that you have lost connection in your XIB file. If commentLabel is still exists you should either delete it and create a new outlet or check the outlets section and delete extra connection and all will be alright!!

EDIT:
This error occurs when you have two outlets connected to the same label in IB.

[image]

Comment: yee it was double connected...That resolved the first Exception...but now i have another exception, as you can see above!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made my custom cell and called it from the class :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[cell reuseIdentifier]];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = customCell;
        customCell = nil;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.serialLabel.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row+1]stringValue];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key commentLabel. ur error stands here ... that means you have not included the class for ur commentLabel... check this out

Comment: i am not really sure what you mean!

Comment: Is ur commentLabel attached to ur xib file via the IBOutlet ?

Comment: but now i get this exception:2012-09-24 12:52:07.761 Speedcheck[1279:907] -[Daten isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e5903d0
2012-09-24 12:52:07.771 Speedcheck[1279:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Daten isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e5903d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x34d532a3 0x3452597f 0x34d56e07 0x34d55531 0x34cacf68 0x3788f37d 0x7a6df 0x79d2d 0x378d654d 0x378bb313 0x378d27cf 0x3788e80b 0x33f05d63 0x33f05901 0x33f06835 0x33f0621b 0x33f06029 0x378948f3 0x34d286cd

Comment: Did u connect it with the delegate ??

Comment: Yep, connected! I think the Mistake must be somewhere here:    [cell setLabelText:[daten objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17060/discussion-between-gill-and-user1370245)

Answer (score 0):

if u are not using the latest ios SDK, make sure that u have written 
@synthesize commentLabel; 
in CustomCell

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the build folder, or try Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings.